# Allowing only one radio button to be checked in each row of grid view

Tags: c#, gridview

Hi guys i used a grid view to insert multiple rows of record into the database . this is how my grid view looks like [image]

The problem is that all radio buttons can be selected , i need only 1 radio button to be selected for each row .. . My web form works in the way where user have to select the correct answer out of the two textboxes with a radio button then i will have to submit the checked answer to database . is this possible?

aspx : `

```
             <asp:ButtonField Text="SingleClick" CommandName="SingleClick"
                    Visible="False" />

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Question">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Answer">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="+" onclick="btnAdd_Click1" />
                        </FooterTemplate>

                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
    </td>
</tr>`
```

code behind :

```
  protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Clear the existing selected row 
        foreach (GridViewRow oldrow in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            ((RadioButton)oldrow.FindControl("RadioButton1")).Checked = false;
        }

        //Set the new selected row
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)rb.NamingContainer;
        ((RadioButton)row.FindControl("RadioButton1")).Checked = true;

    }
```

Comment: paste your grid markup and associated code

Comment: i am newbie to this , i haven't wrote much code behind cos i got totally no idea.... Updated

Comment: Why don't you use [radiobuttonlist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.aspx) ?

Comment: You can also use GroupName property.

Comment: Does GroupName property help ?

Comment: nope GroupName doesn't help , i already did that :p

Comment: Using jQuery refer
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/12/how-to-make-single-radio-button_20.html

Answer (score 10):

I assume you're talking about ASP.NET. Did you try grouping the radio buttons together?

Here's an example.

```
<asp:RadioButton id="rBtn1" GroupName="Fruits"
         Text="Apple" runat="server"/>
<asp:RadioButton id="rBtn2" GroupName="Fruits"
         Text="Orange" runat="server"/>
<asp:RadioButton id="rBtn3" GroupName="Colors"
         Text="Blue" runat="server"/>
<asp:RadioButton id="rBtn4" GroupName="Colors"
         Text="Red" runat="server"/>
```

When Apple is selected, Orange can't be selected. If Orange is selected while Apple is selected, Apple will automatically be un-selected. But when Apple is selected, when you click Blue, Apple won't be un-selected.

Answer (score 2):

Just try to use a `javascript` function like

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function SelectSingleRadiobutton(rdbtnid) {
var rdBtn = document.getElementById(rdbtnid);
var rdBtnList = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (i = 0; i < rdBtnList.length; i++) {
if (rdBtnList[i].type == "radio" && rdBtnList[i].id != rdBtn.id)
{
rdBtnList[i].checked = false;
}
}
}
</script>
```

Grid View

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvdata" runat="server" CssClass="Gridview" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="UserId" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#7779AF" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:RadioButton id="rdbUser" runat="server" OnClick="javascript:SelectSingleRadiobutton(this.id)" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="Name"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField ="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Try to check [aspdotnet](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/12/how-to-make-single-radio-button.html)

Check this [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/enhancing-the-gridview/adding-a-gridview-column-of-radio-buttons-cs)

Hope it works.

Comment: This will generate one radio button per row.. But OP want two radio button per row..and he is not worried about multiple row radio button selection ...he is concerned about within a row multiple radio button should not be selected..

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id="HDDepMood_0" name="DepMood" type="radio"  runat="server" />
Same name for the one group.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may proceed like this :-

```
protected void rbtnSelect_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
RadioButton selectButton = (RadioButton)sender;
GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)selectButton.Parent.Parent;
var radio = (RadioButton)gvRow.FindControl("rdo");// rdo is ID of your radio button:-
if(radio[0].id=selectButton.id)
radio[1].checked=false;
else if(radio[1].id=selectButton.id)
radio[0].checked=false;
}
```

Comment: but i have 2 radio buttons with 2 different ID , can we findcontrol of groupname?  and also where does the .id come about . thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Just add some script to your page to set the groupname:

```
$('input[type=radio]').each(function () {
    var array = $(this).attr('name').split('$');
    $(this).attr('name', array[array.length - 1]);
});
```

This wil adjust the name rendered to the correct group name.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    function singleRbtnSelect(chb) {
        $(chb).closest("table").find("input:radio").prop("checked", false);
        $(chb).prop("checked", true);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: onclick event of radiobutton - call this function in gridview of radiobutton